# How to update a previously created AWS CodePipeline Build Provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-codepipeline

I had previously created a Jenkins build provider using CodePipeline console. During creation, it asks for a Jenkins server URL.

Now, I need to change my Jenkins server URL, but when I try to edit, there isn't any option to change the build provider. See snapshot below:

[image]

**The only solution I see is to add a new one.**

I tried to get the pipeline using aws-cli,

```
aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name <pipeline-name>
```

But the JSON response just has a reference to to the build provider:

```
        ...
        },
        {
            "name": "Build",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "inputArtifacts": [
                        {
                            "name": "APIServer"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Build",
                    "actionTypeId": {
                        "category": "Build",
                        "owner": "Custom",
                        "version": "1",
                        "provider": "jenkins-api-server"
                    },
                    "outputArtifacts": [
                        {
                            "name": "APIServerTarball"
                        }
                    ],
                    "configuration": {
                        "ProjectName": "api-server-build"
                    },
                    "runOrder": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
```

I couldn't find any other command to manage the build provider either. So my question is where and how should I update the existing build providers configuration in AWS CodePipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jenkins action is actually defined as a [custom action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-custom-action.html) in your account. If you want to update the action configuration you can define a new version using the [create custom action type API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codepipeline/create-custom-action-type.html). Your changes will be a new "version" of the action type, so you then update the actionTypeId in your pipeline to point to your new version.

Once you're done, you can also [delete the old version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codepipeline/delete-custom-action-type.html) to prevent it appearing in the action list.

Regarding the Jenkins URL changing, one solution to this is to setup a DNS record (eg. via Route53) pointing to your Jenkins instance and use the DNS hostname in your action configuration. That way you can remap the DNS record in future without updating your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I ended up deleting the custom actions from the cli using "aws codepipeline delete-custom-action-type" and later creating a new one using "aws codepipeline create-custom-action-type". On the URL change, I had to change from http to https. so DNS wasn't an option. Thanks much for your response though.